# How to add GitHub authentication informations in the circleCI config for Package publishing?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, circleci, npm-publish, github-package-registry

I'm setting up the config.yml file for CircleCI in my repo in order for it to publish it as a GitHub NPM package.

Before running the npm publish command, we need to authenticate on the GitHub NPM registry using Username, password (Personnal Access Token) and Email.

I have stored those as Environment Variables and can call them with ${PACKAGE_PAT}, ${PACKAGE_ACCOUNT} and ${PACKAGE_EMAIL}.

So now I have 0 clue about how to add these informations in the process, I would really appreciate some help on that please (first time using a CI).

Here's the config file I've set up so far :

```
version: 2.1

executors:
  my-executor:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10-browsers
    working_directory: ~/repo

jobs:
  build:
    executor: my-executor
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: repo-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
      - save_cache:
          key: repo-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}
          paths:
            - 'node_modules'
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
      - run: npm publish
workflows:
  version: 2
  auto_package_workflow:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - /feature\/FRON-1144.*/
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked and followed the documentation for the npm registry and set my config as this below. Username and email are not necessary. This works great.

```
      - run:
          name: Publish to GitHub Packages
          command: |
            npm set //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${GITHUB_PACKAGE_PAT}
            npm publish
```